# Translation of uniformly continuous function again uniformly continuous?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Let's call a complex-valued bounded function $f$ on a locally compact group $G$ right uniformly continuous if $\forall \varepsilon>0\ \exists e-\text{neighborhood } U: \forall x,x'\in G: x(x')^{-1}\in U\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x')|<\varepsilon$.

Is it always true that $L_gf$ is right uniformly continuous where $(L_gf)(x):=f(g^{-1}x)$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since $x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$ is continuous, if $U$ is as above there exists a neighborhood $U'$ of the identity such that $x(x')^{-1}\in U'$ implies $g^{-1}x(g^{-1}x')^{-1}=g^{-1}(x(x')^{-1})g\in U$.